# While loop seems to ignore "or" operator

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with my code for a "rock paper scissors" game for my Comp Sci class. The part I'm having trouble with is this:

```
while((userscore < 4) || (compscore < 4)){
    if(userhand.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && comphandint == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rock vs. Rock: \nYou Tie");
        }
    else if(userhand.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && comphandint == 1){
            compscore += 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rock vs. Paper: \nYou Loose");
    ...
}
```

The loop works except for the fact that it loops until both userscore and compscore are equal to 4. I want it to loop until only one of the two hits 4. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to use `and` instead of `or` here

Comment: @Lashane that's what is was! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `&&` (and) rather than `||` (or).

A simple logic table shows us the result of both;

```
        |  AND  |  OR

value1  | true  | true 
value2  | false | false

result  | false | true
```

(This is for the benefit of others finding this question later)

So as you can see, with OR if either of the values are below 4 then `true` will be returned and the loop will be entered. With AND, as long as one of the values is 4 or above `false` will be returned and the loop will stop - as you wanted.

Hope this helps you, and anyone else who finds this question in future.